# Setting network namespace when GDM / graphical login is done

Tags: networking, gdm

I am trying to get two different users that share a system to have independent network stacks. I think that I can achieve that thanks to namespaces.

At first, I thought of using `pam_namespace.so`, but that seems to be only for filesystem namespaces.

I am not sure where to "hook" the namespace isolation. It is a multiseat environment, and I am not sure if I can "attach namespaces" according to loginctl or according to who logs in, or some other mechanism.

Is there a standard way of manipulating namespaces on login / on user / on seat?

Comment: Let's hope nothing in your desktop environment relies on detecting devices via libudev [or network namespaces will break it](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2018-July/thread.html#40992). I'm practically sure it will prevent Wayland mode from working properly.

Comment: What do you mean by "independent network stacks", anyway? Something more than just needing different source IP addresses?

Comment: @grawity needing different loopback devices specifically